# Sharepoint 2013 App Restrict File extension

Tags: file, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, file-extension

I am using an App on my site that is kind of a list and allow you to select a file. 
[image]

Is there a way to restrict the file extension that the user can select? Can I do a receiver(event handler) to handle this?

I do not want to restrict the file extension for the whole site. Only for this portion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint Online, this is the list of supported file types that can be stored in SharePoint Online -

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-HA101907868.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102694293

This list is not customizable. Note that SharePoint Online does have virus protection built in to check files when they are uploaded.

Also check:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/149796.

For workarounds:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/239908.aspx